JSON: InlineEditField for specific views only?
The JSON formatting from this thread is working on 3 columns I tested with but I am wondering if there is a way to make a specific column inline editable one a specific view only not in all views?
JSON: InlineEditField for choice columns
Eg We have a Clients list with 2 views, "All Clients" & "My Clients". There are 3 columns we want to be inline editable only on "My Clients" view. So everyone can see all clients but the inline editing is not available on the "All Clients" view to avoid staff accidentally editing someone else's client(s).

This is a known behavior of SharePoint Online JSON column formatting. When you apply column formatting for any column, it is applied at column level (column settings) and not at individual view level (unless column formatting is completely overridden with a rowFormatter in view formatting). However, when using view formatting, you may lost some of the SharePoint default UI options.
Hence, all the views will have same JSON formatting you applied for columns in SharePoint list.
Similar threads:

JSON formatting - remove hyperlink in one view only
Creating Column conditional formatting that are only visible in specific views -  You can try workaround of using calculated columns as explained by @theChrisKent. So, you can create a calculated column which will have same value like JSON formatted column, then you can show calculated column in "All Clients" view and JSON formatted column in "My Clients" view.


Agree with Ganesh Sanap. Column json formatting cannot be only applied to one view.
